# x11-Forwarding fails after subsequent connection

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

Host: Fedora 36, 6.0.18-200.fc36.x86_64, OpenSSH_8.8p1, `X11Forwarding yes`

Client: Windows 10, MobaXterm 22.1

I open the first connection to the host, x11-forwarding works.

```
host01/unix:22  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  5910df423cb206bccd40df7d23132345
host01/unix:21  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  d53c12b33486aa9174722df08219523c
host01/unix:20  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  a5ae8cc54800be76bf34eb0efcfef010
host01/unix:19  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  1ec5c2cc744b058e8a71dda241800271
host01/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  5cefae987f7cb71b941107b99b15c630
host01/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  bf78e1d7b33c7410cb266c548b9732a8
host01/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  048d7933f3212d654fbc84e7f20579c2
host01/unix:14  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  d358f594c3e342e9bafa53bf2419751c
host01/unix:15  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  cdf77dfabbad8be764a5bba194525ffd
host01/unix:16  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c610a4ed220523956fcedb4f6058c06e
host01/unix:17  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  10070d43b0a838bcb8605fe41cb75e49
host01/unix:18  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  18b41e95ffa21a4e2e9c11da03beea07
host01/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  53d8bf1e11674497b602e4c39e0ed928
host01/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  efa99cc0e407d8b23a479b9c7d502d94
```

Now, if I open up another connection on the client to the host. x11-forwarding no longer works on the second connection, but also not on the first, the cookie changes:

```
host01/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  4b50ceb92269a17825ecd011208dbe81
```

The other cookies stay the same.

```
user@host01 ~ $ xterm
MoTTY X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised

In case you are trying to start a graphical application with "sudo", read this article in order to avoid this issue:
https://blog.mobatek.net/post/how-to-keep-X11-display-after-su-or-sudo/

xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Is this fixable? This has worked before, but I am not sure what changed, the host has auto-updates enabled (not Fedora 37 yet).

If I use chattr +i on the file, the following is printed:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  /home/user/.Xauthority not writable, changes will be ignored
/usr/bin/xauth:  /home/user/.Xauthority not writable, changes ignored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "fixed" it myself, but it's only a workaround:

Append to your `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
        xset -q > /dev/null 2>&1
        ret=$?
        if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
                sudo /usr/bin/chattr +i /home/user/.Xauthority
        fi
fi
```

This makes the file write-protected. Subsequent SSH connections will be able to use x11-forwarding. But, if you close your ssh client this won't work again. So:

systemd-timer every minute:

```
#!/bin/bash

conns=$(last -a | grep -i still |grep pts)
ret=$?

if [[ $ret -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "no ssh login found"
        /usr/bin/chattr -i /home/user/.Xauthority
fi
```

This will run every minute, removing the write protection if no ssh user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have a very similar option and have narrowed it down a bit.
System is fully updated with latest version or everything I use.
Kernel vmlinuz-6.0.18-200.fc36.x86_64 Fails
Kernel vmlinuz-6.0.9-200.fc36.x86_64 Works OK.
Sorry I do not have any kernels in between.
So exactly the same software and configuration works with the old kernel but fails with the newer one.

This is all happening on my local network.
My actual problem is that user two connects to my server and remotely tries to display. All good.
Second user (and all after that) connect and when they try to display depending on the program various errors occur but one screen they get
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
(If its the same user then the output from user two appears on user one screen.)
Clearly it is attempting to write to the wrong screen and fails.
Since the error is in the kernel and not on any system program/files I guess only a fix to that code will get this working again.

The only solution I have at the moment is booting on the old kernel. Maybe that will work for you also and at least you can keep going for now.

Comment: Hi All,
just installed
vmlinuz-6.1.5-100.fc36.x86_64
my initial tests indicate the problem is fixed.
Thanks team for the quick fix.